# python - How to remove some tags

Tags: python, regular-language

I have a string like:

```
text = ' A <EM ID="5103" CATEG="ORGANIZACAO" TIPO="INSTITUICAO">Legião da Boa    Vontade</EM> comemora amanhã o <EM ID="5104" CATEG="VALOR" TIPO="CLASSIFICACAO">10º.</EM> aniversário da sua implantação em <EM ID="5105" CATEG="LOCAL" TIPO="HUMANO">Portugal</EM> com cerimónias de carácter religioso e de convívio -- disse ontem fonte da organização. '
```

if i use:

```
     re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', text)
```

i will have something like this

```
A Legião da Boa Vontade comemora amanhã o 10º. aniversário da sua implantação em Portugal com cerimónias de carácter religioso e de convívio -- disse ontem fonte da organização. '
```

but i want to keep the CATEGS .. like `<CATEG= "ORGANIZACAO">`

like:

```
A `<CATEG="ORGANIZACAO">`Legião da Boa Vontade comemora amanhã o `<CATEG="VALOR" >`10º. aniversário da sua implantação em <CATEG="LOCAL">Portugal com cerimónias de carácter religioso e de convívio -- disse ontem fonte da organização.
```

How can i do it?

Comment: the actual output and the expected output look identical to me ...

Comment: will all the non-closing tags have categ as a field?

Comment: i dont understand what are u saying.. 
i have < 3 types of tags > and i want to keep only one of  them.. the tag that i want to keep is <CATEG="...">  .

Comment: This question is so close to being a good fit for BeautifulSoup, if only you didn't want to go from valid XML tags `<EM ID="5103" CATEG="ORGANIZACAO" TIPO="INSTITUICAO">` to invalid `<CATEG="ORGANIZACAO">`, would `<EM CATEG="ORGANIZACAO">` be an acceptable middle ground?

Comment: Are you looking to drop any attribute except `CATEG`? or drop `ID` and `TIPO` and if that leaves more than `CATEG` then so be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [32]: text
Out[32]: u' A <EM ID="5103" CATEG="ORGANIZACAO" TIPO="INSTITUICAO">Legi\xe3o da Boa    Vontade</EM> comemora amanh\xe3 o <EM ID="5104" CATEG="VALOR" TIPO="CLASSIFICACAO">10\xba.</EM> anivers\xe1rio da sua implanta\xe7\xe3o em <EM ID="5105" CATEG="LOCAL" TIPO="HUMANO">Portugal</EM> com cerim\xf3nias de car\xe1cter religioso e de conv\xedvio -- disse ontem fonte da organiza\xe7\xe3o. '

In [33]: re.sub(r'<EM[^C]*(CATEG="[^"]+")[^>]*>', r'<\1>', text).replace(r'</EM>', '')
Out[33]: u' A <CATEG="ORGANIZACAO">Legi\xe3o da Boa    Vontade comemora amanh\xe3 o <CATEG="VALOR">10\xba. anivers\xe1rio da sua implanta\xe7\xe3o em <CATEG="LOCAL">Portugal com cerim\xf3nias de car\xe1cter religioso e de conv\xedvio -- disse ontem fonte da organiza\xe7\xe3o. '
```

The rexeg simplifies the start tags, while the `replace` removes the end tags.

It is a good habit to use raw strings for regexes, do avoid unintended changes in your regex.

Answer (score 2):

(based on your comment that the valid markup can be preserved) If you wanted to leverage a library that is designed to parse and modify HTML this could work (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9045719/16959))

```
import BeautifulSoup

text = ' A <EM ID="5103" CATEG="ORGANIZACAO" TIPO="INSTITUICAO">Legião da Boa    Vontade</EM> comemora amanhã o <EM ID="5104" CATEG="VALOR" TIPO="CLASSIFICACAO">10º.</EM> aniversário da sua implantação em <EM ID="5105" CATEG="LOCAL" TIPO="HUMANO">Portugal</EM> com cerimónias de carácter religioso e de convívio -- disse ontem fonte da organização. '

""" Remove Specific """
REMOVE_ATTRIBUTES = ['id','tipo']
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(text)
for tag in soup.recursiveChildGenerator():
    try:
        tag.attrs = [(key,value) for key,value in tag.attrs if key not in REMOVE_ATTRIBUTES]
    except AttributeError:
        # 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'attrs'
        pass

print(soup.prettify())

""" Keep Specific """
KEEP_ATTRIBUTES = ['categ']
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(text)
for tag in soup.recursiveChildGenerator():
    try:
        tag.attrs = [(key,value) for key,value in tag.attrs if key in KEEP_ATTRIBUTES]
    except AttributeError:
        # 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'attrs'
        pass

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: @Rolan's answer could easily be extended to preserve valid HTML, this is just a different approach

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ElementTree:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse(file_name)
root = tree.getroot()

content = ""
for item in root.iter():
    if item.tag == 'CATEG':
        # Do stuff with item
        content += item.text
    else:
        content += item.text
```