# Removing style from specific tags BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Let's say I have a soup and I'd like to remove all style tags for all the paragraphs. So I'd like to turn `<p style='blah' id='bla' class=...>` to `<p id='bla' class=...>` in the entire soup. But I don't want to touch, say, `<img style='...'>` tags. How would I do this?

Comment: For those who need  to remove some class of a specific tag (python3): 
for x in soup.findAll("p", class_="MsoNormal"):
 del x['class']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over all `p` tags using `find_all('p')` and remove the style attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<body>
    <p style='blah' id='bla1'>paragraph1</p>
    <p style='blah' id='bla2'>paragraph2</p>
    <p style='blah' id='bla3'>paragraph3</p>
    <img style="awesome_image"/>
</body>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    if 'style' in p.attrs:
        del p.attrs['style']

print soup.prettify()
```

prints:

```
<body>
 <p id="bla1">
  paragraph1
 </p>
 <p id="bla2">
  paragraph2
 </p>
 <p id="bla3">
  paragraph3
 </p>
 <img style="awesome_image"/>
</body>
```